# Woocommerce update checkout on custom field change without required fields filled

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to update checkout (totals) on custom field change. Following function works but it only fires when all the required fields are filled.

```
jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' )
```

Is there any way to trigger this update without fully completed form?

Answer (score 1):

We need to know a bit more about this custom field you have created, specifically the input name. Here is how you can update the checkout totals based on billing state / county change. Notice the name of the field, "billing_state".

```
/**
 * Snippet Name:    WooCommerce Update Checkout Totals On Billing Sate / County Change
 * Snippet Author:  ecommercehints.com
 */

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ecommercehints_update_checkout_totals' );
function ecommercehints_update_checkout_totals() { ?>
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'select[name^="billing_state"]', function() {
        $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
    });
});
</script>
<?php }
```

You'll need to replace the name to your custom field.

Comment: You didn't understand the question. It is not about the field itself. Field works, also the jQuery code works but only when you fill up the whole address. I want to trigger update_checkout without having all the required fields filled.